# Create a function that dynamically create classes

Tags: python

I have read many posts on how to create dynamic classes in python using type.

But i want to create a function that takes as argument the class name and fields (attributes and functions). It uses type to create classes.

```
def create_model(name, fields=None):
    model = type(name, (object,), fields)
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fields = {
        'first_name': 'abc',
        'last_name': '10',
        '__str__': lambda self: '%s %s' (self.first_name, self.last_name),}
    model = create_model('Person', fields)
    print model.first_name
    print model.__str__
    # prints <unbound method Person.<lambda>>
```

I want to define class such that it can take any type of value for attributes.

Comment: It works; your function creates a a **class**. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a class, quite properly too. But special methods like `__str__` need to be *called*, and for `str()` to work, it needs to be used on an **instance**:

```
model = create_model('Person', fields)
person_instance = model()
print person_instance
```

You do need to fix the `__str__` lambda, it is missing a `%`:

```
'__str__': lambda self: '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Demo:

```
>>> fields = {
...     'first_name': 'abc',
...     'last_name': '10',
...     '__str__': lambda self: '%s %s' %(self.first_name, self.last_name),
... }
>>> model = create_model('Person', fields)
>>> person_instance = model()
>>> print person_instance
abc 10
```

Comment: @user3731594: right, that's because your `__str__` method was missing the `%` operator.